# Cannot read property "querySelectorAll" of null when loading external js file window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving the error Cannot read property "querySelectorAll" of null when trying to load a table from a .js file on window.onload.  If I put the table directly on the HTML page it loads fine, but when putting the table in an external js file and making a call onload is when I receive the error. I have tried moving the variables at the bottom and that didnt work.  My goal here is to use the drop down to filter by state, then be able to search for keywords in the search by that specific state.  Thanks for the help!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>States</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="Header">


</div>


<div id="MainBody">


<h2>Search</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInputJob" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="" title="Type Here">

  
  <select id="StateDropdown" oninput="filterTable()">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>CA</option>
  <option>WA</option>
</select>

<div id="TableJob"></div>

</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Manuals2.js"></script>
</html>
```

js

```
window.onload = function() {
  
  GetManuals();
}

var table = document.getElementById("myTableJob");
var tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); 

function myFunction(event) {
var input, filter, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInputJob");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
table.style.display = ""
if (document.getElementById('myInputJob').value == '') { 
table.style.display = "";

} else {
table.style.display = "";

}
    td_1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    td_2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    td_3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    
    if (td_1 || td_2) {
   if (td_1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 || td_2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  } 
}

function filterTable() {
  // Variables
   
  let dropdown, table, rows, cells, state, filter;
  dropdown = document.getElementById("StateDropdown");
  table = document.getElementById("myTableJob");
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  filter = dropdown.value;

  // Loops through rows and hides those with countries that don't match the filter
  for (let row of rows) { // `for...of` loops through the NodeList
    cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    state = cells[1] || null; // gets the 2nd `td` or nothing
    // if the filter is set to 'All', or this is the header row, or 2nd `td` text matches filter
    if (filter === "All" || !state || (filter === state.textContent)) {
      row.style.display = ""; // shows this row
    }
    else {
      row.style.display = "none"; // hides this row
    }
  }
 tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not([style="display: none;"])');  
}

</script>
```

external .js file

```
function GetManuals() {
var data = '<table id="myTableJob"> \
<tr class="header"> \
<th>City</th> \
<th>State</th> \
<th>Keyword1</th> \
<th>Keyword2</th></tr> \
<tr><td>San Francisco</td><td>CA</td><td>Gray</td><td>Red</td></tr> \
<tr><td>San Diego</td><td>CA</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr> \
<tr><td>Seattle</td><td>WA</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr> \
<tr><td>Salt Lake City</td><td>UT</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr> \
<tr><td>Las Vegas</td><td>NV</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr> \
</table> '
document.getElementById('TableJob').innerHTML =data; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data to the variables after calling the `GetManuals`.

```
  let table, tr;

  window.onload = function () {
    GetManuals();
    table = document.getElementById('myTableJob');
    tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  };
```